Handling new values with MudBlazor Autocomplete (CoerceValue=true)
I'm trying to create a component which allows the user to both select existing customers and type in a new customer by name.
I use CoerceValue so that the _customer variable will either be null or the selected customer. This works fine, but the value is reset if the component receives focus again
If I set CoerceValue to false, the value isn't reset, but the _customer variable isn't set to null once the user changes the text either.
Online sample here: https://try.mudblazor.com/snippet/mkGoFaQYfaDSEUeD
@using System.Threading
<MudAutocomplete
    T="CustomerModel?"
    Value="@_customer"
    ValueChanged="CustomerChanged"
    CoerceValue="true"
    SearchFunc="SearchFunc"
    ToStringFunc="ToStringFunc"
    Text="@_text"
    CoerceText="false"
    TextChanged="OnTextChanged">
    <ItemTemplate>
        @context.Name (id: @context.Id)
    </ItemTemplate>
</MudAutocomplete>

@code {
    [Parameter] public CustomerModel? Customer { get; set; }
    [Parameter] public string? Text { get; set; }
    [Parameter] public EventCallback<CustomerModel?> CustomerChanged { get; set; }
    [Parameter] public EventCallback<string?> TextChanged { get; set; }

    private CustomerModel? _customer;
    private string _text = string.Empty;

    protected override void OnParametersSet()
    {
        _customer = Customer;
        _text = Text ?? string.Empty;
    }

    private async Task OnValueChanged(CustomerModel? customer)
    {
        _customer = customer;
        await CustomerChanged.InvokeAsync(customer);
    }

    private async Task OnTextChanged(string text)
    {
        _text = text;
        await TextChanged.InvokeAsync(text);
    }

    private string ToStringFunc(CustomerModel? arg)
    {
        return arg?.Name ?? string.Empty;
    }


    private List<CustomerModel> CreateCustomerList()
    {
        return
        [
            new CustomerModel { Id = 1, Name = "Customer 1" },
            new CustomerModel { Id = 2, Name = "Customer 2" },
            new CustomerModel { Id = 3, Name = "Customer 3" }
        ];
    }

    private Task<IEnumerable<CustomerModel>> SearchFunc(string text, CancellationToken cancellationToken)
    {
        var result = CreateCustomerList();

        if (!string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(text))
        {
            result = result.Where(x => x.Name.Contains(text)).ToList();
        }

        return Task.FromResult<IEnumerable<CustomerModel>>(result);
    }

}

